# Python list of integers length error

Tags: python, list, types, integer

I have the following code, Python2:

```
def sumofN(lst):
    wtf = len(lst)

    if wtf == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in lst:
            su = sumofN(lst[i]) + su
    return su

l = [1,3,5]

print sumofN(l)
```

When I am running it I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

However, it is obvious that l is not an integer but a list of integers. What is going on?

Comment: When you call `sumofN(lst[i])`, what do you think happens?

Comment: I guess its content is summed to su variable. I am not changing the list. Or am I?

Comment: I would recommend you use e.g. http://pythontutor.com/ to step through your code in a visual manner. I'd guess you will be surprised by what it's doing; your code at the moment makes very little sense. Frankly, given the apparent requirements, `sumofN = sum` would suffice, but you should investigate your current implementation if only to understand why it's very wrong.

Comment: I am just practicing recursions so it is very likely my code is not correct> regardless, it is very unintuitive what is going on. Let me go through the code as you have suggested

Comment: Just to add to this, you've both recursion and iteration in your code. Pick one or the other :)